# How to add footer to the Deedy resume?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, templates, cv

You can view the template by googling Deedy resume.

I  want to add a footer bearing my address at the end. How do I do so?
The TeX code (only the beginning and the end are as shown)

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}
```

Column one:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
```

Column two:

```
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
```

End:

```
\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). **That is the way here to say "Thank you for the help!"**

Answer (score 1):

In the class file you can find the command

```
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry}
```

You need a larger `vmargin`.  You can change this by using command

```
\geometry{% <===========================================================
  hmargin=1.25cm, 
  vmargin=1.75cm, % <===================================== to get footer
  showframe % <========================== to show typing area and footer
}
```

in your preamble of your cv.

With the changed example cv from the used class

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Deedy - One Page Two Column Resume
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.2 (16/9/2014)
%
% Original author:
% Debarghya Das (http://debarghyadas.com)
%
% Original repository:
% https://github.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume
%
% IMPORTANT: THIS TEMPLATE NEEDS TO BE COMPILED WITH XeLaTeX
%
% This template uses several fonts not included with Windows/Linux by
% default. If you get compilation errors saying a font is missing, find the line
% on which the font is used and either change it to a font included with your
% operating system or comment the line out to use the default font.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% TODO:
% 1. Integrate biber/bibtex for article citation under publications.
% 2. Figure out a smoother way for the document to flow onto the next page.
% 3. Add styling information for a "Projects/Hacks" section.
% 4. Add location/address information
% 5. Merge OpenFont and MacFonts as a single sty with options.
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% CHANGELOG:
% v1.1:
% 1. Fixed several compilation bugs with \renewcommand
% 2. Got Open-source fonts (Windows/Linux support)
% 3. Added Last Updated
% 4. Move Title styling into .sty
% 5. Commented .sty file.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Known Issues:
% 1. Overflows onto second page if any column's contents are more than the
% vertical limit
% 2. Hacky space on the first bullet point on the second column.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{street and number; postcode city; country} % <===================
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} % <================================

\geometry{% <===========================================================
  hmargin=1.25cm, 
  vmargin=1.75cm,
  showframe
}


\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     LAST UPDATED DATE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lastupdated

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     TITLE NAME
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href{http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\
\href{mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN ONE
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EDUCATION
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Education} 

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{MEng in Computer Science}
\location{Dec 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
\sectionsep

\subsection{Cornell University}
\descript{BS in Computer Science}
\location{May 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
College of Engineering \\
Magna Cum Laude\\
\location{ Cum. GPA: 3.83 / 4.0 \\
Major GPA: 3.9 / 4.0}
\sectionsep

\subsection{La Martiniere for Boys}
\location{Grad. May 2011|  Kolkata, India}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     LINKS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Links} 
Facebook:// \href{https://facebook/dd}{\bf dd} \\
Github:// \href{https://github.com/deedydas}{\bf deedydas} \\
LinkedIn://  \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/debarghyadas}{\bf debarghyadas} \\
YouTube://  \href{https://www.youtube.com/user/DeedyDash007}{\bf DeedyDash007} \\
Twitter://  \href{https://twitter.com/debarghya_das}{\bf @debarghya\_das} \\
Quora://  \href{https://www.quora.com/Debarghya-Das}{\bf Debarghya-Das}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     COURSEWORK
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Coursework}
\subsection{Graduate}
Advanced Machine Learning \\
Open Source Software Engineering \\
Advanced Interactive Graphics \\
Compilers + Practicum \\
Cloud Computing \\
Evolutionary Computation \\
Defending Computer Networks \\
Machine Learning \\
\sectionsep

\subsection{Undergraduate}
Information Retrieval \\
Operating Systems \\
Artificial Intelligence + Practicum \\
Functional Programming \\
Computer Graphics + Practicum \\
{\footnotesize \textit{\textbf{(Research Asst. \& Teaching Asst 2x) }}} \\
Unix Tools and Scripting \\

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     SKILLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\section{Skills}
%\subsection{Programming}
%\location{Over 5000 lines:}
%Java \textbullet{}   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascript \\
%OCaml \textbullet{} Matlab \textbullet{} Rails \textbullet{} \LaTeX\ \\ 
%\location{Over 1000 lines:}
%C \textbullet{} C++ \textbullet{} CSS \textbullet{} PHP \textbullet{} Assembly \\
%\location{Familiar:}
%AS3 \textbullet{} iOS \textbullet{} Android \textbullet{} MySQL
%\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%     COLUMN TWO
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     EXPERIENCE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Experience}
\runsubsection{Facebook}
\descript{| Software Engineer }
\location{Jan 2015 - Present | New York, NY}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Coursera}
\descript{| KPCB Fellow + Software Engineering Intern }
\location{June 2014 – Sep 2014 | Mountain View, CA}
\vspace{\topsep} % Hacky fix for awkward extra vertical space
\begin{tightemize}
\item 52 out of 2500 applicants chosen to be a KPCB Fellow 2014.
\item Led and shipped Yoda - the admin interface for the new Phoenix platform. 
\item Full-stack developer - Wrote and reviewed code for JS using Backbone, Jade, Stylus and Require and Scala using Play
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Google}
\descript{| Software Engineering Intern }
\location{May 2013 – Aug 2013 | Mountain View, CA}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Worked on the YouTube Captions team, in Javascript and Python to plan, to design and develop the full stack to add and edit Automatic Speech Recognition captions. In production.
\item Created a backbone.js-like framework for the Captions editor.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Phabricator}
\descript{| Open Source Contributor \& Team Leader}
\location{Jan 2013 – May 2013 | Palo Alto, CA \& Ithaca, NY}
\begin{tightemize}
\item Phabricator is used daily by Facebook, Dropbox, Quora, Asana and more.
\item I created the Meme generator and more in PHP and Shell.
\item Led a team from MIT, Cornell, IC London and UHelsinki for the project.
\end{tightemize}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     RESEARCH
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Research}
\runsubsection{Cornell Robot Learning Lab}
\descript{| Researcher}
\location{Jan 2014 – Jan 2015 | Ithaca, NY}
Worked with \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ashesh/}{Ashesh Jain}} and \textbf{\href{http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/}{Prof Ashutosh Saxena}} to create \textbf{PlanIt}, a tool which  learns from large scale user preference feedback to plan robot trajectories in human environments.  
\sectionsep

\runsubsection{Cornell Phonetics Lab}
\descript{| Head Undergraduate Researcher}
\location{Mar 2012 – May 2013 | Ithaca, NY}
Led the development of \textbf{QuickTongue}, the first ever breakthrough tongue-controlled game with \textbf{\href{http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/~tilsen/}{Prof Sam Tilsen}} to aid in Linguistics research. 
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     AWARDS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Awards} 
\begin{tabular}{rll}
2014         & top 52/2500  & KPCB Engineering Fellow\\
2014         & 1\textsuperscript{st}/50  & Microsoft Coding Competition, Cornell\\
2013         & National  & Jump Trading Challenge Finalist\\
2013     & 7\textsuperscript{th}/120 & CS 3410 Cache Race Bot Tournament  \\
2012     & 2\textsuperscript{nd}/150 & CS 3110 Biannual Intra-Class Bot Tournament \\
2011     & National & Indian National Mathematics Olympiad (INMO) Finalist \\
\end{tabular}
\sectionsep

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     PUBLICATIONS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\section{Publications} 
%\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5cm} % Couldn't get this working from the .cls file
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
%\bibliography{publications}
%\nocite{*}

\end{minipage} 
\end{document}
```

you get the following result (please see that I commented the last rubric in column one and two to get one page!):

[image: resulting cv]

Answer (score 0):

See the top of page 6 in the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf). Modify the footer commands as you see fit.

Also you need to change the `vmargin` in the `.cls` file to `\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.75cm]{geometry}` so that the footer is visible. I got the `.cls` file from [here](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/blob/master/OpenFonts/deedy-resume-openfont.cls).

```
\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% comment out what you don't want
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\textbf{The performance of new graduates}}
\lfoot{From: K. Grant}
\cfoot{To: Dean A. Smith}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth} 
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want it in 'article' class but in `\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}`

Comment: The `vmargin` in the `.cls` file is too small to see it. Just change the `.cls` file from `\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=0.75cm]{geometry}` to `\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.75cm]{geometry}`.